# ui-bootstrap module angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I want to use pagination for angular from ui-bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) but I am not sure if I have to add ['ui.bootstrap'] module in my app.js file or in the controller of the view. For example, if I want my main.view.hmtl to have pagination, do I have to add this module to main.controller.js or is it enough to have it in app.js?

Comment: You have to add it to your app definition like this --> angular.module('myApp, [ui.bootstrap]')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find it easily

> Installation As soon as you've got all the files downloaded and
>   included in your page you just need to declare a dependency on the
>   ui.bootstrap module:
>
> angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
>
> if you are using UI Bootstrap in the CSP mode, e.g. in an extension, make
>   sure you link to the ui-bootstrap-csp.css in your HTML manually.

from link [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)